# symfony2 doctrine join

Tags: symfony, doctrine, left-join

Okay, so i've got a query that i've researched and researched how to get this to work and for the life of me i cant!...  perhaps i'm just doing this incorrectly and the minimal information ive found..

I've got a table named timeclock setup..  which has a field: noteBy_id in it which is an id to the user the record belongs to...

What I need to do now, is for the management side of things in the system..  I anticipate more than 1 company using this timeclock system, and as such I need to filter the results based on the company id..  In the user table, i have a field named `parentcompany_id`

So, lets see if I can express in words what I need to do..

I need to Select * from timeclock and left join user.parentcompany_id where timeclock.daydate < :start and where u.parentcompany = :pid

where start is: `date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');

I've setup this query:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$start = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
$qb = $em->getRepository('EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock');
$qb = $qb->createQueryBuilder('t');

$query = $qb->select('t, u.parentcompany_id')
->from('timeclock', 't')
->leftJoin('Ecs\AgentManagerBundle\Entity\User', 'u', 'ON' 'u.id = t.noteBy_id AND u.parentcompany_id = :pid')
->where('t.daydate < :start')
->andWhere("t.noteBy_id != ''")
->setParameter('start', $start)
->setParameter('pid', $user->getParentcompany())
->getQuery();

$entities = $query->getArrayResult();
```

I've looked and looked and can't find a solution to the error that I get which is:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Semantical Error] line 0, col 112 near 'u ON u.id = t.noteBy_id': Error: Identification Variable Ecs\AgentManagerBundle\Entity\User used in join path expression but was not defined before.") in EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock:manager.html.twig at line 5.
```

and the query that gets output is:

```
SELECT t, u.parentcompany_id FROM Ecs\CrmBundle\Entity\TimeClock t LEFT JOIN Ecs\AgentManagerBundle\Entity\User u ON u.id = t.noteBy_id AND u.parentcompany_id = :pid, timeclock t LEFT JOIN Ecs\AgentManagerBundle\Entity\User u ON u.id = t.noteBy_id AND u.parentcompany_id = :pid WHERE t.daydate < :start AND t.noteBy_id != ''
```

which under normal circumstances would work perfectly...  but in this, it just doesn't...  Any ideas?

Comment: I just noticed, the code above is giving me 2 LEFT JOINS instead of just 1...  So who knows where the real issue is...

Comment: with the help of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399355/query-builder-dql-not-working-with-inner-join-syntax-issue

I got this fixed.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently had to do it like this..  I'm guessing in this that your noteBy is a ManyToOne in the user table and you are wanting to have it filter the results by the company of the admin that is currently logged into your system..

So, adapting a join I had to write myself for such a task is easy enough.  I personally like to use the QueryBuilder so this will be done in query builder..

Your first mistake in your query is the `->from('timeclock', 't')` line.  Because you have previously created your object with `$qb = $em->getRepository('EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock'); $qb = $qb->createQueryBuilder('t');` you don't need the `from` in the query builder, as it will be generated for you.

The next issue, is the leftJoin and I'll explain why when I've shown you a working version.

And the last issue, preventing this from working how you want it - is a missing `andWhere` clause.  So, lets take a look at a working query.

```
$query = $qb->select('t, u')
     ->leftJoin('t.noteBy', 'u', 'WITH', 'u.id = t.noteBy')
     ->where('t.daydate < :start')
     ->andWhere('u.parentcompany = :pid')
     ->setParameter('start', $start)
     ->setParameter('pid', $user->getParentcompany()) 
     ->getQuery();
```

So because we've already created the object by using `$qb = $qb->createQueryBuilder('t')` we just select `t` and `u`

For the join, we're joining the timeclock table by the `noteBy` column, which is the user id from the user table.  So, the first argument being the "from" alias.  So, since we've aliased the timeclock table with t we use `t.noteBy`.    The next argument in the leftjoin is the alias of the 2nd table, which is `u` in this case but can be anything..  The third argument for a leftJoin anyway - is the way you join it..  either a `WITH` or `ON` will work here.  and the 4th argument, is the match you wish it to have.. in this case `u.id must equal t.noteBy`

You will see that I got rid of one of the `andWhere`, I did this because with the properly structured query you shouldn't need it.  I did however add in the `andWhere` for the `u.parentcompany` since that is afterall what you are looking to filter by you should have it in a WHERE instead of as a match in the join itself.

The documentation is very limited in this, and it took me a while to figure it all out as well..  You, undoubtedly - like me, came to using doctrine from writing your queries by hand.  And So since you seem to be just starting with Symfony (i am myself as well about 2 months in now), you're still in the hand-coding mindset.  But with further time, you'll start understanding the DQL way of life.  Try this query out and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first you would need to relate entity `Timeclock` to `Company`. Whenever you want to join two entities in `Doctrine` they need to be related by some attribute (that is, table column).

I don't see any need for `User` entity in this query as all info is available through `Company` entity and you are not filtering down results based on any user properties.

You desired query should look something like this (more or less). I took liberty and ditched `_id` suffixes from entity attributes as they tend to cloud what is really going on. ;)

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("SELECT t, c.id FROM EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock t JOIN t.company c WHERE c.id = :pid AND t.daydate < :start AND t.noteBy != ''");

$query->setParameter('start', $start);
$query->setParameter('pid', $user->getParentcompany());
return $query->getArrayResult();
```

Also, I did `inner-join` (`JOIN`) as I think there could not be timeclock without it's company but feel free to change that to `LEFT JOIN` if that suits you better.

Is this what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: The Company Entity is in another Bundle just like the User Entity..  The issue with your solution, for me anyway, is the TimeClock table has a reference to the ID of the User, so it's the users table has the parentcompany inside of it not the timeclock table..  So I have to use the users table to filter the results by the current logged-in managers company...